# Can you have multiple one to one relationships with the same name inverse relationship in the Core Data Model in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, inverse

When I try to make the inverse relationship of a entity equal to the same as another one to one relationship's inverse I chose, it replaces the other one I chose. Why can't I have multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how Core Data works. A relationship may (and should) have an inverse relationship. It can't have multiple inverse relationships. If you assign an inverse where one already exists, you replace that inverse. What you're seeing is normal and expected.

Comment: So instead of creating 3 one to one, my only option is have 1 one to many relationship? I have already chosen this method, but wanted to know if I could find a work around. I'm glad you understood my question... I was tired when I wrote it.

Comment: You can have one to many relationships, or multiple one to one relationships, depending on what makes sense for your data.

Comment: but not with the same inverse variable name?

Comment: The "inverse variable name" is the name of the inverse relationship, so no.